# Can an arduino control a large servo motor?

Tags: arduino, robotic-arm, servomotor

A I wanting to build a robotic hand, a big one at that. Similar to this one but in a much larger scale:

http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Robotic-Hand-Controlled-by-a-Glove-and-Arduino/

Does it really matter how large the servo is, just as long as it has a power source? Or are there other things I need to know?

Answer (score 1):

It does matter how large/small the servo is.
The bigger you get (in the arm), the more you will have to account for the inertia of the moving arm.
There are a lot of types of servos... from micro ones, to really big ones.
I would suggest building the current arm as-is, and then actually building the bigger one.

Comment: The full idea is to build a robot that mimics a person's movement. This was inspired by pacific rim, except the robot will be much, much smaller. That is the end goal, the prototype will be the size of a normal human, but as the years go by, I plan to make them bigger, and stronger, don't say Im an idiot because "The robot is too large, and it will break its legs upon standing up", I already know this, the max size of the robot will perhaps be 10 - 12 ' tall if I can ever get it to that point.

Comment: The robots will be controlled by a pilot hiding in a bunker, so they will pretty much function like drones.

Comment: @KennethCarrington, that sounds awesome.  I suggest you actually build the current arm as-is (current scale).  After that, then build it bigger.  Also, download the movie Robo Jox (original, not the 2nd part).